# Can I reuse content (single source) in markdown?

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

Disclaimer: I am a tech writer (not developer, so KIS and be kind please).

I write in Markdown. Each MD file is paired with an RST file that serves as either an index to the section (listing multiple files) or, for a topic, just provides a path to the MD. For example:

.. markdown-ingest::
    :filename: ./users-guide/deploy/inventory.md

Ultimately we use Sphinx to generate the documentation. I'm trying to find a way to reuse some markdown content so that I can create unique documents for specific audiences. In my mind, a document might look like:

Gouda bavarian bergkase mozzarella...

`<include dairy-free-content>`

Cheesecake mozzarella cauliflower cheese...

Anyone know of a way to do this? My book is getting grossly bloated. Thanks...

Comment: Standard Markdown does not offer support for anything like that. More specifically, last I checked, the Markdown implementation used by Sphinx does not offer support for any extensions.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

With [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) and [python-markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/) you can use the [snippets](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/) extension to include markdown content.